# Forward Form.MouseWheel event to TextBox

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events

I have a Form, which has 2 TextBoxes. One of them is MultiLine and ReadOnly. The other one is for typing commands, so I want it to be in focus all the time.
Is it possible to forward the MouseWheel event of the Form to a TextBox, so I can scroll in the TextBox without having it in focus?
If not, what is the best workaround?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the mouse wheel event of the form to get the scroll value, and then set the scroll of the TextBox manually, using ScrollToCaret().

```
textBox.SelectionStart = scrollPosition;
textBox.ScrollToCaret();
```

To get the scroll value, use the MouseWheel event: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousewheel(v=vs.71).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.mousewheel%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)